# Windows Batch - How to automatically send the users prompts for a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file and Inside that batch file I will invoke another batch file. The second batch file which I invoked will ask the user two times to enter the ENTER-Key.  We are automating the batch and I don't want the user to enter the ENTER-Key manually.
 So how can i automate it so that the ENTER key stroke is given automatically.

I tried by invoking the below command:

```
test.bat < Input.txt
```

With the above command it didn't work.

Give me your suggestions on this.

Comment: Why not simply removing the lines (most likely `pause` commands) that wait for keystrokes from the 2nd batch?

Comment: take a look at [sendkeys.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/sendKeys.bat)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need vbs. Name file something.vbs

```
Set sh = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sh.Run "notepad.exe", 9
WScript.Sleep 1000 'wait a while to load notepad app'
sh.AppActivate "Command Prompt"
sh.SendKeys "Hello World!"  
sh.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
WScript.Sleep 100'
sh.SendKeys "^p"
```

Esc is `{ESC}`

Comment: I'm invoking a another batch file instead of a notepad.exe, that batch file needs some input from the user. so i need to send that keystrokes.

Comment: It's sample code for you to change to suit your circumstances.